# How to get the unresolved dynamic path in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to use `usePathName` to get the current page's path for analytics. I have a dynamic page `product/[product_name]` and log it exactly in that format, but `usePathName` is returning `product/product1`, `product/product2`, etc. Is there a way to override `usePathName` on a specific page, or get the unresolved dynamic path in some other way? For analytics, I just care about how many times the product details page has been visited in aggregate.

I'm using NextJS 13.2